# Local Node.js Server Recieve and Send messages to component on website

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to run a local Node.js server, or listen for events and then run other Node functions, but also emit messages too.

So, for example lets say within my CMS I have a button labeled `Start Watch`. If I click this I want to emit and even using `Socket.io` which my local Node script on the machine will see, and then run some more code, in this case it would be `gulp watch`.

Then in the other direction during the watch, if files are uploaded I want to be able to emit this to my CMS to update the user visually that a file was uploads or something.

This is completely wrong I think but this is my attempt, but doesn't work!#

### Vue Component on CMS

```
<template>
    <h2>Chat Testing</h2>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        let socket = require('socket.io');
        socket.emit('connection', []);
    }
}
</script>
```

### Local script on laptop:

```
let app = require('express')();
let http = require('http').createServer(app);
let io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the package `socket.io-client` on the client.

First you need to connect to the server.

[Client API](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/)